# not getting the data from Serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

view.py

@csrf_exempt

def blog_list(request):

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    post = Post.objects.all()
    serializer = BlogSerializer(post, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data,safe=False)

elif request.method == 'POST':
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = BlogSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

class BlogSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

```
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ['author', 'title',  'text',  'published_date']
```

class Post(models.Model):

```
author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
text = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to understand a few things about this code

```
def blog_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post = Post.objects.all()
        serializer = BlogSerializer(post, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data,safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = BlogSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Here *request* referes to a *request* object, which contains all the data inside the request (method, body, data, headers, etc), and not just the request data. So, you want to parse **request.body**, instead of *request*.

```
data = JSONParser().parse(request.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `request.data` to serializer. Passing whole request won't return anything, because request does not have fields you declared in serializer. They are in post data.

Comment: I didn't get anything please may you explain.

Comment: In get method .